# Проблема с кодировкой в VS Code

Tags: python, кодировка, requests, beautiful-soup

Есть такой код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

from requests.models import encode_multipart_formdata

HOST = 'https://minfin.com.ua/'
URL = 'https://minfin.com.ua/cards/'
HEADERS = {
    "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36"
}

def getHTML(URL, params=''):
    response = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return response

def getContent(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.findAll('div', class_ = 'sc-14ydfjo-0')
    print(items)

html = getHTML(URL)
getContent(html.text)
```

При его выполнении в VS Code (через coderunner) получаю ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Danil\Desktop\parser\parser.py", line 24, in <module>
    getContent(html.text)
  File "c:\Users\Danil\Desktop\parser\parser.py", line 21, in getContent
    print(items)
  File "C:\Users\Danil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2009' in position 1283: character maps to <undefined>
```

Этот же код выполняется в pycharm без ошибок. Понятно, что проблема в кодировке, но как ее пофиксить - не знаю

Comment: Для начала попробуйте `getContent(html.content)`, беря в обработку один только `.text` вы лишаете `BS` информации о кодировке файла, записанной в служебных заголовках `html`-я.

Comment: К сожалению ошибка осталась

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте записать в файл вместо вывода на печать, причём записать в кодировке `UTF-8`. У вас ошибка с выводом на экран, при попытке перекодировать в `cp1251` (родную кодировку Windows) строку с символом, которого нет в `cp1251`. Воспроизведение проблемы:

```
print('\u2009'.encode('cp1251'))
```

Вывод:

```
...
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2009' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

Запись в файл:

```
with open('test.txt', 'w', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    f.write('\u2009')
```

Ошибок нет.

P.S. И в любом случае лучше делайте так: `getContent(html.content)`, беря в обработку один только `.text` вы лишаете `BS` информации о кодировке файла, записанной в служебных заголовках `html`-я.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А еще такой вопрос: через requests я загружаю страницу, а затем записываю её html код в файл. Но в файле вместо русских символов появляются иероглифы. При записи в файл указывал аргумент encoding как "utf-8", так и как "windows-1251", но не помогает ничего из этого. Можно как-то исправить?

Comment: @TRXTSSA А чем вы смотрите файл? Смотрите программами, которые умеют понимать `UTF-8`. В `Google Colab` ваш код и печатает русские буквы нормально, потому что там `Linux` и родная кодировка `UTF-8`.

Comment: Просматриваю через notepad++